# Play scraper empty response

Tags: python

I'm running some basic code with python.
I'm using https://pypi.org/project/play-scraper/ play-scraper.

When launching the command print(play_scraper.details('com.android.chrome')) I get back

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'
```

I've tried to debug the issue and the problem seems that it returns an empty list:

```
section_titles_divs = [x for x in soup.select('div.hAyfc div.BgcNfc')]
```

Till few weeks ago I was reciving something like this:

```
{
    'app_id': 'com.android.chrome',
    'category': ['COMMUNICATION'],
    'content_rating': ['Everyone'],
    'current_version': 'Varies with device',
    'description': 'Google Chrome is a fast, easy to use, and secure web browser. Designed for Android, Chrome brings you personalized news ...',
    'description_html': 'Google Chrome is a fast, easy to ... Chrome web browser experience you love across all your devices.<br/> <br/> <b>Browse fast and type less.</b> ...',
    'developer': 'Google LLC',
    'developer_address': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View 94043',
    'developer_email': 'apps-help@google.com',
    'developer_id': '5700313618786177705',
    'developer_url': 'http://www.google.com/chrome/android',
    'editors_choice': False,
    'free': True,
    'histogram': { 1: 672180, 2: 288519, 3: 735220, 4: 1560066, 5: 6033423},
    'iap': False,
    'iap_range': None,
    'icon': 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nYhPnY2I-e9rpqnid9u9aAODz4C04OycEGxqHG5vxFnA35OGmLMrrUmhM9eaHKJ7liB-',
    'installs': '1,000,000,000+',
    'interactive_elements': ['Unrestricted Internet'],
    'price': '0',
    'recent_changes': u"Thanks for choosing Chrome! You can now find your saved passwords more easily \u2013 just tap the new Search icon in Settings > Passwords. We've also included stability and performance improvements.",
    'required_android_version': 'Varies with device',
    'reviews': 9289408,
    'score': '4.3',
    'screenshots': [ 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lKPDNfsO2QhJD9i77rGDTiH5ILjXlXwPsRi194hhkY4BsbaXbpCFrdjWvcU1zttUwqXz=w720-h310-rw', ...],
    'size': 'Varies with device',
    'title': 'Google Chrome: Fast & Secure',
    'updated': 'May 10, 2018',
    'url': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome',
    'video': None
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should your code handle an empty list? Does your code call a `select` method? If so, please include that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue this morning. I changed in utils:
additional_info_data = parse_additional_info(soup.select_one('.IxB2fe'))

to

additional_info_data = parse_additional_info(soup.select_one('div.IxB2fe'))

The page was loading two refs to the above selector and the first result was the incorrect one. I'm assuming it used to be where there was only one result to match against.

Hope this helps! I had fun this morning, that's for sure.